# How to download the files using the links in a list?

Tags: python

I am new to python and stuck on a problem.

I have a list which contains the name and link for meeting recordings

ex: `downloadlist[(name1, link1), (name2,link2), (name3,link3),(name4,link4)]`

This above list is made by using `zip`:

```
downloadlist = list(zip(chaptername,all_downloadlinks))
```

where `chaptername` and `all_downloadlinks` are two separate lists

I want to download the files using the links and name those files using the names. How can I establish this in python?

Also can we download it one by one? Because downloading multiple files at once would choke the bandwidth. Maybe we can just download one, show progress bar for the current download and once that is done download the next one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Here is a [`requests` tutorial by Corey Schafer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tb8gHvYlCFs), it should cover downloading files, rest is simple python logic, if you want to get help you need to provide a [mre] and state the issue with the current code

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych sure. i agree with you, i should have posted the code that i tried.

Comment: If they don't unlock it, then here is the answer https://pastebin.com/pcFFEP7E

Comment: @nigani the question is unlikely to be reopened and also there already is an answer but most importantly such questions really shouldn't be answered, the issue being that OP has not shown enough research effort and other things that are not in compliance with SO, tho I am not entirely sure

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following snippet that uses Python's `requests` module (you have to install it using `pip`) to download a file:

```py
import requests
# Define the remote file to retrieve
remote_url = 'https://www.google.com/robots.txt'
# Define the local filename to save data
local_file = 'local_copy.txt'
# Make http request for remote file data
data = requests.get(remote_url)
# Save file data to local copy
with open(local_file, 'wb') as file:
    file.write(data.content)
```

Taken from [BetterProgramming's GitHub profile](https://github.com/BetterProgramming).

You can then wrap that code in a `for` loop and download everything in your lists.

Comment: It's best to avoid posting links to off-site resources that are likely to eventually break. Please put the code *in* you answers here.

Comment: i agree, edited